# What's the precedence of styles and themes in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I had a hard to debug problem where I wanted to have a layout file with buttons that were completely styled from the Activity code. Because `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` can't be set by themes and need be set by specific `style="@style/myButton"` in the layout files, everything went spaghetti.

Bottom line is I can't use themes to completely control styles from the `Activity` code. But completely generating layouts in the `Activity` code is painful because you don't get the `Graphical Layout View` to easily preview changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this wonderful blog post](http://growingupwithandroid.blogspot.co.il/2010/03/order-precedence-in-styling.html) I found a few days too late.

1. Widget's inline attributes, which override the ...
2. Styles in the styles.xml file, which override the ...
3. Default styles of the widget, which override the ...
4. Theme specified styles