# Precedence of themes/styles?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-appcompat, android-styles

Given:

- Four AppCompat activities A, B, C and D.
- Four custom defined Themes (T1, T2, T3 and T4) that inherit from AppCompat themes.

Also:

- T1 is applied in manifest file to the application.
- T2 is applied to A inside the manifest file
- T3 is applied programatically to B in onCreate()
- T4 is applied in the root element for C's layout file.

What will be resultant Theme in each Activity at run time? Do themes take presedence? Do they get combined or overwrite each other?

What happens to D if T2 is applied to it inside the manifest file, then T3 programmatically and layout file applies T4?

In what order do the styles get applied using various combinations of ways?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.... What have you observed when running the code?

Comment: Have similar similar set up, don't get what is going on. Setting theme programatically/in layout doesnt do anything, setting Application and T2 to A results in some kind of merge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the precedence of styles and themes in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12653988/whats-the-precedence-of-styles-and-themes-in-android)

Comment: Id argue not quite

Comment: You must call setTheme before setContentView, if that's what you're doing that doesn't work.

Comment: `Setting theme programatically doesnt do anything` How do you do that?

Comment: @cricket flagged this error

Comment: What error? I don't think the fact that you have Appcompat themes is any different. If an answer were to be posted here, it should be posted there instead since it's already top result of "Android theme precedence" in some search engines

Comment: @cricket I had settheme after setContentView.

Comment: My previous comment said before SetContentView. If that isn't working, show examples of each of your bullet points in code

Comment: I wanted to know how does android use each of the methods described above @cricket_007

Comment: And I'm simply trying to point out that it shouldn't be that difficult to write a simple application yourself to play around with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> T1 is applied in manifest file to the application.

This is applied to the whole app, you get the theme you extended and anything you overwrote there. For example, app-wide Toolbar colors are a common one to put here.

> T2 is applied to A inside the manifest file

You've created a new theme dependency chain for this one Activity, unless you used the same parent as the app theme, it'll have independent properties, like a different Toolbar color.

You'll still maintain application settings, like a hidden system UI / full screen theme.

> T3 is applied programatically to B in onCreate()

This overrides anything set in the manifest for that activity, and shouldn't be different than T2

> T4 is applied in the root element for C's layout file.

This only affects that one view. For example, if the app or Activity uses a FullScreen theme, then that would still be applied, but you additionally have stylized this view.

For example, the root view could simply be a TextView. It doesn't have to be a RelativeLayout, FrameLayout, CoordinatorLayout, etc.

You normally wouldn't apply application / activity level styles to these individual views. Nor, do I think those attributes get applied within the source code

---

Note: there's no concernable difference between `styles.xml`and `themes.xml`

---

You may read more about defining parent attributes at [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: What about setting theme in the layout.xml? Then 1. Programmatic overrides manifest. 2. manifest.activity overrides manifest.app?

Comment: Depends which element of the XML you're talking about. A style on the top RelativeLayout, for example, is a separate theme than the manifest.activity, which is still different than manifest.app

Comment: If you apply it to route element eg. T2 is child of NoToolbar and T3 is child of base apppcompat theme. Apply T3 in manifest and T2 to root element in layout xml. Activity then wont have a toolbar

Comment: The content view of an Activity is inflated after its theme is applied. Applying a NoActionBar theme to the root element of that layout should still have a toolbar, unless I've mistaken something. You normally wouldn't apply Activity themes to anything but an Activity, though